# How to make scrollable layouts each one fits screen width?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'm trying to make android app which has a scrollable `layout` that scrolls different other `layouts` vertically and horizontally, I want each layout of theses different layouts to fits the screen width and nearly fits the Height, look at the following figure that illustrates what I'am trying to do:

[image]

I just tried to set all *width* and *height* of these layouts to `match_parent` and put all of them in a **main_layout** assigned with `match_parent` parameters also, then I create a `Layout` and put the Layouts(4,1,5) in it and put this `Layout` in a `ScrollView` , then i put the **main_layout** layout in a `HorizontalScrollView` that contains three layouts(Layout3, Layout(4,1,5), Layout2), but that gave me an interfered view of the Layouts.

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.9" >

        <!-- just to give it 0.9 of the screen in order to give a space to the top layout (it takes 0.1 and the weight sum is 1) -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Layout3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Layouts(4,1,5)"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/Layout4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/Layout1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/Layout5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Layout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: this would give some idea, https://github.com/LambergaR/VerticalViewPager/

Answer (score 1):

i'd try that:

`RelativeLayout` instead of `ScrollView`

all `LinearLayout`s with `match_parent`, transformed programmatically:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int sw = size.x; // screen width
int sh = size.y; // screen height

LinearLayout lay2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout2);
lay2.setTranslationX = sw;

LinearLayout lay3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout3);
lay2.setTranslationX = -sw;

LinearLayout lay4 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout4);
lay2.setTranslationY = -sh;

LinearLayout lay5 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout5);
lay2.setTranslationY = sh;
```

and then touch listener on `RelativeLayout` that would control swipes, changing it's position.

Answer (score 0):

I found all i needed in that [link](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/12/android-swipe-view-tab-layout-example.html) , it provides a sample project source code that achieves the approach i needed by depending on Android fragmentation in a way easy and efficient way (but this way can provide horizontal navigation only). 
And so, after a searching i found this [library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager/) that provides the process in both directions(vertically & horizontally)